# How can i get the cacheManager from shiro framework in any part of application

Tags: java, shiro

How can I get a reference to the cacheManager object in the Shiro framework in any part of my application? For example, I want to remove the old user data that was cached during the removal of a user or updating its permission.
Right now I am handling it following way

```
public void cleanUserCache(final String userName) {
        final EmbeddedCacheManager embeddedCacheManager = securityRealmsProducer.getEmbeddedCacheManger();
        final Cache<Object, Object> authenticationCache = embeddedCacheManager.getCache("JPA-Auth-Realm.authenticationCache");
        final Cache<Object, Object> authrizationCache = embeddedCacheManager.getCache("JPA-Auth-Realm.authorizationCache");
        final Object userAuthenticationInfo = authenticationCache.get(userName);
        if (userAuthenticationInfo != null) {
            authenticationCache.remove(userName);
            final SimpleAuthenticationInfo principle = (SimpleAuthenticationInfo) userAuthenticationInfo;
            final SimplePrincipalCollection simple = (SimplePrincipalCollection) principle.getPrincipals();
            authorizationCache.remove(simple);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is wrong with what you are doing?  Also, have you looked at the Singleton pattern?  This problem is pretty much what it is for!

Comment: You have to be careful with the singleton pattern.  You're susceptible to concurrency issues with initialization if you do it lazily.

Answer (score 0):

If this class is the only place you're utilizing the cache, you can hold a final reference to the cache.  There's no use in calling to get the cache manager and caches over and over.

I would recommend doing it in the constructor if you know the cache manager is initialized at that point.